# Regex Query: Remove escape characters but retain punctuations from a string

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string

I have a string that goes like - `"\n\n\some text\t goes here. some\t\t other text goes here\b\n\n\n"`.

What I want - `"some text goes here. some other text goes here."`

Here is what I am doing: `re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ', s)`

Problem is that this removes all the punctuations as well. How do I retain those?

Comment: Note that `\s` is an unknown escape sequence. As for punctuation, do you only want to keep ASCII punctuation or any? If only ASCII, try ``re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9!-/:-@[-`{-~]+', ' ', s).strip()``. See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/nYNH6E).

Comment: So, are you sure you have that `"\s"`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that finds all the escape characters in your string and then removes them.

```
r = repr(s)  # Convert escape sequences to literal backslashes
r = r[1:-1]  # Remove the quote characters introduced by `repr`
escapes = set(re.findall(r'\\\w\d*', r))  # Get escape chars
answer = re.sub('|'.join(map(re.escape, escapes)), '', r)  # Remove them
# \ome text goes here. some other text goes here
```